# Replace value from one file with value from another file in linux

Tags: linux

I've been trying to figure this out all day.  Any help would be appreciated.

fileA has the following data.

```
a bal=45
b bal=40
c bal=55
d bal=65
```

fileB has the following

```
a type ppm func,bal=#,oth,new
b type ppm,bal=#,oth,new
c type ppm func,bal=#,oth,new
d type ppm,bal=#,oth,new
```

I'm trying to find a way to replace bal=# in fileB with the value bal=XX in fileA by matching the the first column of both files.

Output would look like:

```
a type ppm func,bal=45,oth,new
b type ppm,bal=40,oth,new
c type ppm func,bal=55,oth,new
d type ppm,bal=65,oth,new
```

fileB is both space and comma delimited and the column b=# is in will not be the same for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v OFS="," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{split($1,t,/ /);$2=a[t[1]]}1' fileA FS="," fileB
a type ppm func,bal=45,oth,new
b type ppm,bal=40,oth,new
c type ppm func,bal=55,oth,new
d type ppm,bal=65,oth,new
```

We set the output field separator to `,`. We read fileA in to an array `a` having key as column1 and value as column2 by using the `NR==FNR` and `next` construct. Once the file has been loaded, we move to the second file. We split the first column on space using `split` function. We set the second column to the value from the array and print the line using `1` which by default prints the line.

Notice we set the input field separator to `,` for the second file by placing it right before the file name at the end.